# Xcode lazy regular expression

Tags: regex, xcode, regex-greedy, non-greedy

I'm trying to replace something like this:

```
NSSomeFunction(@"some var", @"another one")
```

With:

```
NSSomeOhterFunction(@"some var")
```

In Xcode. So these are source files...
I bet the regular expression will look something like this:

```
NSSomeFunction\((.*), .+\)
```

But I need this to be lazy. Otherwise .+) will match the last parenthesis occurrence rather than the first (for example both parenthesis in the end would be replaced with a single one given this string: "NSLog(@"%@", NSSomeFunction(@"hey", @"lol"))" ).

How to do lazy search like this? I think you can do this in pearl using the modifier /U (ungreedy). Though Xcode does not seem to support that.

Comment: The `/U` modifier is found in PHP, not Perl, and it makes all quantifiers non-greedy by default, or greedy if followed by `?`.  To quote Friedl, "I would guess that the primary effect of this pattern modifier is to create confusion, so I certainly don't recommend it." http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/regex3/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usually the ? will indicate non-greedy match, so for .+) you would use .+?)